# Change the data type of a column for multiple excel files using macros

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion

I have received 3100 excel files in one folder. Each excel consists of 3 columns and my problem is that in some of the files the 3rd column is text and in some nvarchar. I want to transform the 3rd column of all my files to text. 
I have no experience with VBA , however I recorded the Macro and captured the coding in the console for a single file.

Anybody that can help me build the loop entering each file?
My folder's name is OCR.

```
ChDir _
    "T:\OCR"
Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: If you post the code you have in a Code Block someone may be able to help.

Comment: The important bit you'll need is `.Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"`. There are lots of posts around about how to loop through and open/close excel files